# Checkbox with link which make appear a paragraph in a form

Tags: forms, checkbox

I'm working on a form and I need to do this: http://www.isoluxcorsan.com/es/contacto/
I refer to the checkbox with link, which when clicked open a text paragraph.

Sorry for the name of the topic but I really don't know how to call it better.

Thanks in advance,
Kevin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page loads set the textbox containing the paragraph to 'visibility = false'.
Then when the link is clicked set the visibility = true for the textbox.

so basically.

```
MyTextBox.visibile = false; (on page load)
MyTextBox.visibile = true; (on link click)
```

Comment: Hi Callum,

Thanks for your response, but can you be more specific please? I can't find the way to do what you say.